# IPC using Linux pipe

Tags: linux, pipe

I have doubt in using Linux Pipes for IPC. My question is

Can Linux pipes can be used to communicate  between the processes running on different machines?.

Thanks,

Comment: You can also check the slides http://man7.org/conf/lca2013/IPC_Overview-LCA-2013-printable.pdf about different IPC's in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use only `pipe` to communicate between different machines, because pipe is defined as local machine communication method ([IEEE standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/pipe.html) says that it creates two file descriptors in current process. Descriptors usually can't be send to other machine, only inherited from parent or [passed via local machine sockets](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch17lev1sec4.html)).

But you can try to use pipe to some external socket program, like `netcat`, which will resend all data over tcp socket, and remote `netcat` will replay it back into the program.

And if you are developing some application, it can be better to use tcp `socket`s directly.

PS: The IPC - Inter-process communication - AFAIK means communications between different processes on one (same) machine ([linux IPC](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node8.html#SECTION00710000000000000000) from Linux Programmer's Guide 1995).

PPS: If sockets are hard to work with them directly, you may choose some **Message Passing** library or standard. For example MPI standard (OpenMPI, MPICH libraries) is often used to communicate between many machines in tightly-coupled [computing clusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster), and there are some popular interfaces like RPC ([Remote procedure call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), several implementations) or [ZeroMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZeroMQ)

Answer (score 0):

Pipe is only used for communication between related process on the same host (eg. parent and child process).